# Which configuration settings should be used to prevent "No statistics available" in the Admin Reports?

Tags: 7, log-messages

When I view the Admin Reports like Top Referrers, Top Pages, Top Users, etc (by navigating to /admin/reports), those pages simply say "No statistics available". I am using Drupal version 7 with an admin account with all permissions.

Google Analytics is successfully collecting this data, so I don't understand why Drupal is not. I can't find any configuration setting to enable these reports. Could this be an issue with my webhost?

I apologize if this post is vague. I just don't know how to go about diagnosing this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Google Analytics or your Provider. Check `/admin/config/system/statistics`. This will populate your `/admin/reports/hits`.

Comment: This is correct! I wish Drupal was a little more descriptive about this.

Comment: That's why we are here 4 ;-) glad to help.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to give a link to /admin/config/system/statistics on /admin/reports/hits, It could have saved lots of time for so many people and there was no need for this question on SE ;)

Comment: I like the idea about that "link"! But more then 2 years later now, in D7 version 7.34 it seems to still be missing. Why not go ahead and submit a patch for it. That is really not "so difficult", Drupal is open source, everybody can pinpoint the exact location to get it added, and contribute a patch for it. Or is this yet another "George will do it" sample (as in the keynote from Dries in DrupalCon A'dam 2014)?